# why does Qt Webkit render differently to Chromium webkit

Tags: qt, webkit

I tried viewing a webapp I've built in the Qt HTML5 template project. However, this renders somewhat differently to what I see on Chrome or Chromium... E.g. the fonts look slightly different, and things such as

```
display:flex;
```

in css doesn't seem to work at all in the Qt view... As a beginner to Qt, why is this? With the same render engine I expected everything to look identical (I'm of the understanding that it's the render engine that deals with the css as well as the html).

If I'd like my app to look as nice in Qt as it does in Chrome/Chromium, will there be a lot of work in adding additional libraries manually? Do I need to manually use a more up-to-date version of webkit in Qt (indeed, is that even possible)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you're somewhat confused about which browser layout engine is which.  To clarify:

- QtWebKit is based on Apple's WebKit (which in turn is a fork of KDE's KHTML)
- Recent versions of Google Chrome/Chromium are based on Google's [Blink](http://www.chromium.org/blink) (which is a fork of Apple's WebKit.)  Older versions were based on WebKit.

While WebKit and Blink are pretty similar, they're not exactly the same.  According to MDN WebKit's implementation of flex [is still named with the vendor prefix, -webkit-flex,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) because Apple hasn't updated to the latest W3C specs yet.

Also note that Qt is moving to Blink as well with [the upcoming QtWebEngine](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtWebEngine).